# How to set Content-Type of a Webbrowser Control?

Tags: .net, com, webbrowser-control, mshtml, contenttype

Is it possible to set the Content-Type of a document in a webbrowser control?

For example how can I show an XML document rendered as XML in a webbrowser control by using DocumentText?

Answer (score 0):

Try add an extension to your [IMoniker::GetDisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680754(v=VS.85).aspx) [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2/source/browse/trunk/General_Classes/LoadHTMLMoniker.cs). This will cause the URL moniker to [look under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.??? keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691433(VS.85).aspx) for mime types. Then you can use the [webbrowser's documen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domdocument(v=VS.90).aspx)'s [IPersistMoniker interface to load the moniker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx).