# ActiveX component to display in-memory MHTML in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, activex, mhtml

I'm creating a small Windows application (C++) which create some windows an such ([CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the like). And in one window I want to add a control that shows [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mhtml) loaded from memory, i.e. the whole MHTML content is in a string, not in a file.

I already tried the `Shell.Explorer` component, but I can't find a way to inject to it anything other than HTML (see [AtlAxCreateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da181h29.aspx)).

Is it possible to use the Shell.Explorer component or any other to show in-memory MHTML??
That is, without writing the content to a file and then giving the file path. That works, but it's not optimal and it'll have to be the last alternative if I can't do it any other way.

PS: If this can be done in another language or environment like C#, JS, VBS, WSH, HTAs, I'm all ears as well.

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to answer, but still - there is a way to do it : use Microsoft's WebBrowser control (COM component, can be used in .Net apps as well).

Take a look an what the proposed solutions here - [How to load mht from stream/string into a WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705139/how-to-load-mht-from-stream-string-into-a-webbrowser-control) and here - [How to display the string html contents into webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362591/how-to-display-the-string-html-contents-into-webbrowser-control). some of them refer to mhtml content but the solutions are applicable to ordinary html files as well.

Good luck.